# Java HTTP Server GZIP gives content encoding error

Tags: java, http, gzip

I have this part in a method, It should return the page and headers to the web browser.

`tSend` is a wrapper class for a string, `getSub` just brings back another instance of the class, a sub component. `tSend.get()` is a string that is the page, `tSend.getSub().get()` is a string that contains the response headers for the page.

However, in firefox it is giving a Content Encoding Error

Code:

```
{
    tSend.getSub().println("Content-Length: " + tSend.get().length() + "\r");
    if (gzip) {
        tSend.getSub().println("Content-Encoding: gzip\r");
    }
    tSend.getSub().println("\r");
    if (mom.DEBUG)
        System.out.println("Sending to client");
    out.println(tSend.getSub().get());
    if (gzip) {
        byte[]bytes = tSend.get().getBytes();
        GZIPOutputStream outGZIP = new GZIPOutputStream(out);
        outGZIP.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
        outGZIP.finish();
    } else
        out.println(tSend.get());
}
```

I have Changed the class for tSend, also I have just included the class for it. The class is just to kind of buffer the response so I could use the content length to allow me to do keep-alive in my http server.

Code:

```
  public static class ToSend
  {
     private String string = "";
     private ToSend sub;
     public void setSub(ToSend nextLevel)
     {
        sub = nextLevel;
     }
     public ToSend getSub()
     {
        return sub;
     }
     public String get()
     {
        return string;
     }
     public void set(String s)
     {
        string = s;
     }
     public void print(String s)
     {
        string = string + s;
     }
     public void println(String s)
     {
        print(s + "\n");
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm confused why you call `tSend.getSub().addln()` and `tSend.getSub().println()` for tasks that feel identical to me.

I don't think you should send the `Content-Length:` header if you compress the content -- you won't know the size until after the compression is finished.

You send content down `out.println()` before you've attached the gzip encoder to it -- is this intentional? You also forget the CR `\r` on that line -- is that intentional?

Does `tSend.get()` create any side-effects that make debugging this code difficult? Does `tSend.getSub()` or any methods called on *it* have any side-effects that complicate debugging?

Comment: `.addln()` and `.println()` are the same, they are just there to make integration easier. I know `content-length` is needed for keep-alive connections. I send tSend.getSub() down because it is the headers for the page, from what I know those shouldn't be encoded, `\r` should all be contained in `tSend.getSub()`. `tSend.get()` just returns a String, `tSend.getSub()` just returns the nested class for `tSend`

Comment: Ah, so it's some hold-over to try to make legacy code easier to deal with. I'm sure I wouldn't be the only one confused by the difference, so it'd be best to stick to one method or the other completely when writing new code. :)

Comment: I have done some more simplification to the code, getting rid of the `addln` and `add` methods of the class, that on instance was the only one so I just removed it. I also added the `tSend` class